# Python, finance/accounting and nested data

Tags: python, finance, hash

I have this type of data:

```
entity, account, month1, month2, ..., month12
abc, 2000.02, 1,3,...,3
abc, 2000.01,2,3,...,5
xzf, 1000.00, 2,4,...,6
```

I need to add up all the entities, but first I need to get "calculated" fields. For example, in entity abc, the account "2000" is equal to "2000.01+2000.02".

At the moment I have it all in a python dict. The struct is:

```
d = {("abc","2000.01"):[month1,...,month12],("abc","2000.02"):[month1,...,month12],...}
```

The first thought to do this would be using eval (yes I know the problems with eval) and do:

```
s = "d[("abc","2000.01")]+d[("abc","2000.02")]"
eval(s)
```

I need a string as I will be reading a configuration file where I will map and configure all the accounts. So in the conf file I will write something like "2000=2000.01+2000.02".

However, 2 problems:

1 - Not sure this is the best most pythonic solution

2 - Some entities do not have all the accounts. In the example above, if "2000.02" is missing in entity xvz, then the eval will throw a KeyError, but that is wrong because xvz may have "2000.01" and that should go in "2000"

Also, if there is any embeddable database that may be suitable for this kind of operation, I will like to look at it too. At the moment I am thinking to use persistent python dictionaries.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve your code "s = ..." (if fixed by enclosing in single quotes) would just combine two list, but as a wanted result you showed a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you'd like to group the values according to the 1st part of your key (`'abc'` for instance) without taking into account the 2nd part (`'2000.01'` or`'2000.02'`). This should work:

```
>>> d = {('abc', '2000.01'): ['month1', 'month12'], ('abc', '2000.02'): ['month1', 'month12']}
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d2 = defaultdict(list)
>>> for (k1, k2), v in d.items():
    d2[k1] += v


>>> d2
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'abc': ['month1', 'month12', 'month1', 'month12']})
>>> d2['abc']
['month1', 'month12', 'month1', 'month12']
```

Using `defaultdict` allows not to test if the key `k1` already exists in dict `d2`. This should work whatever your values. I used strings instead of objects for `month1, month12` because it was easier to test but it will work as well.